# Centred texts with different sizes in responsive SVG image

Tags: html, svg

How can one get a **scalable** SVG image with texts with **different sizes**, all centred both **vertically and horizontally**?

What I would like to achieve:

[image]

What I have tried so far ([JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8KVtU/658/)):

```
<text x="50" y="30"
        style="text-anchor: middle;alignment-baseline:middle" 
        fill="black" font-family="'Arial'" font-size="20">
            H1 HEADLINE</text>

<text x="50" y="45"
        style="text-anchor: middle;alignment-baseline:middle" 
        fill="black" font-family="'Arial'" font-size="15">
            H2 HEADLINE</text>
```

Thanks in advance for any tips :) I cannot use JavaScript.

Comment: I think we have to calculate the center point ***manually***. And even doing like so can just find the approximate vertical offset of the center point. In CSS we have absolute positioning with percentage and the `translate` transform knowing about the dimension  of the translated object so we can set `left:50%; top:50%` and `translate(-50%,-50%)` to center the shape flexibly. But in SVG relative (percentage) can't be used that way. That's why we are stuck. If the font-size and the text are fixed, you can calculate the center point once.

Comment: Can you use `<foreignObject>` to embed HTML inside your 'responsive' SVG? I am assuming so; with this you can create an HTML table layout using CSS, and embed an `<svg>` element within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [section 10.1 of SVG 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#Introduction):

> SVG performs no automatic line breaking or word wrapping. To achieve the effect of multiple lines of text, use one of the following methods:
>
> - The author or authoring package needs to pre-compute the line breaks and use multiple ‘text’ elements (one for each line of text).
> - The author or authoring package needs to pre-compute the line breaks and use a single ‘text’ element with one or more ‘tspan’ child elements with appropriate values for attributes ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘dx’ and ‘dy’ to set new start positions for those characters which start new lines. (This approach allows user text selection across multiple lines of text -- see Text selection and clipboard operations.)
> - Express the text to be rendered in another XML namespace such as XHTML [XHTML] embedded inline within a ‘foreignObject’ element. (Note: the exact semantics of this approach are not completely defined at this time.)

As such, you need to either manually calculate the vertical location to get vertical centering, or use `<foreignObject>` to embed HTML+CSS within your SVG (at the correct location) which *can* perform vertical centering, e.g. using `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle`.